# Debugging data abort and prefetch abort exceptions on Windows CE 6

Tags: c#, compact-framework, arm, windows-ce

We're running a rather complex software on Windows CE and Windows Mobile for mobile data acquisition on different device types. On the only device type with Windows CE 6.0 installed, our client randomly freezes the operating system (so a warm-boot is required). The client might runs well for one or two days before freezing, but it can be five minutes as well (already checked on handle and memory leaks). In the log file of the device manufacturer, such entries appear when the device freezes:

> Exception 'Data Abort' (4): Thread-Id=070a003e(pth=89ca07e0),
>   Proc-Id=0709003e(pprc=8a01d3d0) 'OurClient.exe',
>   VM-active=0709003e(pprc=8a01d3d0) 'OurClient.exe'
>   PC=41a66b28(mscoree3_5.dll+0x00056b28)
>   RA=41a64ab4(mscoree3_5.dll+0x00054ab4) SP=0003e28c, BVA=00000132

The messages differ from time to time (I'd say I counted 20 different ones so far, with exceptions in kernel.dll, k.core.dll or nk.exe).

So my question is basically, how can I debug such an error occurring in the depths of the .NET framework and the kernel? For example, how can I translate the program counter into a method inside the mscorlib (same for the return address)? Is it likely that our program doesn't work well with CE 6 or could this be a driver issue as well?

**Update:** It turned out, that one of the device drivers interferes with our keyboard hook implementation.

Comment: There will probably be a .kdmp file in `/windows/system/dumpfiles`. You can use WinDBG + psscor2 to analyze it. (I don't know if psscor2 is compatible with WinMo or not).
This is almost certainly caused by native code, so the next best thing would be to stub out all of your p/invoke calls and see if it still happens and slowly add them back in. Consider writing a separate app that just runs those p/invoke calls repeatedly to see if exercising them in a loop will cause the issue to happen more quickly. 
Yes, this could be a driver (or other platform component) issue.

Comment: The firmware doesn't seem to be configured to generate dump files. I'm currently looking into our P/Invoke calls. Thanks for your comment :)

Comment: That may be the case, but be aware that `dumpfiles` is a hidden directory. You may need to enable "menu->show all files" to see it. Also, the .kdmp file is deleted by the system after the "we're sorry" dialog is dismissed, so you need to look for it before dismissing the crash dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Alan points out, if you don't have the symbols an source for where things broke (and with `mscoree3_5.dll`, you don't) then the abort information is pretty useless.  Even with the source, you can't walk it back without the compiler symbol output.

At this point you can only take educated guesses.  The fact that the exception info all looks valid (i.e. the RA or SP is non-zero) indicates to me that it's not a stack issue, it's more likely a data issue (maybe an alignment, maybe a bad read or write pointer).

My guess is that it's from an incorrect P/Invoke.  The fact that it "moves" indicates that it's likely an object reference or address passed to a P/Invoke going invalid due to collection or compaction.

Imagine the following scenario.

You have a native API that takes in a pointer to some data blob that said API will use not just immediately, but periodically.  Maybe it reads from it or writes to it, but the key is that the API needs the data not just synchronously at the time of the call.  The API necessarily stores that pointer for it to use at a later point.

You create some managed code that calls this API though a P/Invoke.  To pass the data pointer you define a class that represents the data, create an instance of the class and pass it across.  Let's say, for the sake of the example, that the address is 0x500.

You run your app, the API is called and all is well. The API reads from 0x500 and goes about its business.

Until the app triggers a GC.  Now the GC says "hey, I have some empty space in the heap, I'll move some stuff around to fix that".  It moves the managed object so that it's now at 0x200 and frees the memory at 0x500.  At some point after that, the API goes to it's pointer, still at 0x500 and does a read.  The OS says "hey, that unallocated space, you can't do that!" and it aborts.

The fix to this scenario is to use a Pinned GCHandle.  Instead of passing the class to the API, you pin the class and pass in the GCHandle's address, which the GC cannot move during collection or compaction.  This ensures that the address remains constant for the like for the GCHandle and is safe to pass across the native boundary.

Notice that this scenario happens without using unsafe code at all, though you could do the same with unsafe code. In fact I'd argue that with unsafe code you'd likely be more cognizant of where it might happen and that could would be "safer" than the code not marked as unsafe.  Avoiding the `unsafe` keyword doesn't prevent unsafe code.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was thinking... somewhere you are passing something that is either invalid or no longer valid (invalid) to a p/invoke

Comment: Here is a neat [article on memory management](http://community.intermec.com/t5/General-Development-Developer/Slaying-the-virtual-memory-monster/td-p/16764) I stumbled upon today while researching the Intermec drivers. There are links to several old tools I didn't already know about. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I don't believe that it is possible with what you are given (outside of MS) to debug a native exception like this and find out what in mscoree3_5 was being called at the time. It's been a while since I looked into doing this, but I do remember finding there was a reason this couldn't be done. Perhaps, it was because I didn't have the debug symbols, or perhaps it was some other nature of the .NET runtime, I can't recall.

However, I have had success with translating data abort messages to understand the meaning of the exception which helped...

In your exception:

RA: Return Address
BVA: Base virtual address
PC: Program counter
SP: Stack pointer
FSR: Fault status register

I'm sorta surprised your exception did not include the FSR, did you truncate it? This is what helped find a mis-aligned read etc. I have a good link which helps describe how to debug these messages:

[Printed Exception strings - what do all those flags mean?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hopperx/archive/2005/06/29/433842.aspx)

Comment: Actually there's no FSR information in our log file (which is generated by the firmware in some way). Thanks for the explanation of the flags btw.

Comment: We're using P/Invoke, but we don't have any `unsafe` blocks.